# XML transformed failed

Tags: java, xml, xslt, encoding, utf-8

I am using XML transformer to transform an XML to another XML some how. Some none English characters transformed failed.

Original xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0 xmlns:RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0="http://apply.grants.gov/forms/RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0-V2.0" xmlns:att="http://apply.grants.gov/system/Attachments-V1.0" xmlns:glob="http://apply.grants.gov/system/Global-V1.0" xmlns:globLib="http://apply.grants.gov/system/GlobalLibrary-V2.0" RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:FormVersion="2.0">
   <RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:KeyPerson>
      <RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:Profile>
         <RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:Name>
            <globLib:PrefixName>候.</globLib:PrefixName>
            <globLib:FirstName>Lakshmi</globLib:FirstName>
            <globLib:MiddleName>AB</globLib:MiddleName>
            <globLib:LastName>Sørensen</globLib:LastName>
         </RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:Name>
      </RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:Profile>
   </RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:KeyPerson>
</RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0>
```

removeemptytags.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*[text()[normalize-space()] | @*])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

java code:

```
public String removeEmptyTags(String xml) {
    String filteredXML = "";
    try (OutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource inputXMLSource = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        StreamSource xsltSource = new StreamSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("removeemptytags.xsl"));
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos);
        transformer.transform(inputXMLSource, result);
        bos.flush();
        filteredXML = bos.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception while removing empty tags : ", e);
        throw new ParsingException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return filteredXML;
}
```

ouput xml:

```
<RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0 xmlns:RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0="http://apply.grants.gov/forms/RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0-V2.0" xmlns:att="http://apply.grants.gov/system/Attachments-V1.0" xmlns:glob="http://apply.grants.gov/system/Global-V1.0" xmlns:globLib="http://apply.grants.gov/system/GlobalLibrary-V2.0" RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:FormVersion="2.0">
<RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:KeyPerson>
<RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:Profile>
<RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:Name>
<globLib:PrefixName>ÃƒÂ¥Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢.</globLib:PrefixName>
<globLib:FirstName>Lakshmi</globLib:FirstName>
<globLib:MiddleName>AB</globLib:MiddleName>
<globLib:LastName>SÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¸rensen</globLib:LastName>
</RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:Name>
</RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:Profile>
</RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:KeyPerson>
</RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0:RR_KeyPersonExpanded_2_0>
```

As you can see the "non-English words" just become bunch of nonsense characters. I try to change encoding in xslt to "UTF-16" but it doesn't work. Does anyone encounter the same issue in here ?

Comment: Did you set the output's encoding to UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get that many weird characters, you seem to have multiple encoding issues.

First, when reading the XML into the `xml` String *(code not shown)*. Can't really help with this one, since we don't know how you did it wrong, though you likely forgot to specify `UTF-8` encoding.

Second, when calling `bos.toString()`. If you want result as a `String`, don't use an `OutputStream`. Use a `StringWriter` (see code below).

Third, when you write the string to a file *(code not shown)*. Again, can't really help with this one, since we don't know how you're doing that, though you likely forgot to specify `UTF-8` encoding.

```
public String removeEmptyTags(String xml) {
    try (StringWriter out = new StringWriter()) {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource inputXMLSource = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        StreamSource xsltSource = new StreamSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("removeemptytags.xsl"));
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);

        transformer.transform(inputXMLSource, new StreamResult(out));
        return out.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception while removing empty tags : ", e);
        throw new ParsingException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Actually, it would be better to do it all directly from/to files, and let the XML library figure out encodings:

```
public void removeEmptyTags(Path inFile, Path outFile) {
    try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(inFile);
         OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(outFile)) {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource xsltSource = new StreamSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("removeemptytags.xsl"));
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);

        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(in), new StreamResult(out));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception while removing empty tags : ", e);
        throw new ParsingException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct!!. I did encoding multiple times. In output,  I need result as a String. I just simply use byte[] b = StringUtils.toBytesUTF8(filteredXML) to do encoding.